# Raspberry Pi headless, my if [[ file1 -nt file 2 ]] that thinks the two files have the same modified date

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh

So I have a player script "player.sh" and an updater script "updater.sh".

player.sh plays any mp3 file in /home/filepath/ using a wild card *.mp3, this works as expected.

what I want is for the updater.sh  to sleep for 15 seconds, then mount the usb drive "sda1" to /media/pi, then check whether the *.mp3 in /media/pi is newer than the *.mp3 in home/filepath/

If the file is newer, it pkills the mp3 playback, uses RM to purge all *.mp3 from /home/filepath/, copies the newer *.mp3 into /home/filepath/, then starts the player.sh back up again to play the new file.

however, it doesn't do this....

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ] ; do
sleep 15
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/pi
if [[ /media/pi/*.mp3 -nt /home/filepath/*.mp3 ]] ; then sudo pkill mpg123 & sudo rm /home/filepath/* & cp /media/pi/*.mp3 /home/filepath/ & sh /home/filepath/player.sh & echo "updated"
else echo "not updated"
fi
sudo amount -l /media/pi
done
```

I just get a terminal full of "not updated".

No matter what I do the script thinks the files have the same modified date, but I have checked the files using "stat" and the modified dates are many hours apart.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you say something like `[[ /dir1/* -nt /dir2/* ]]`, the shell expands that to look like

```
[[ /dir1/f1 /dir1/f3 … -nt /dir2/f2 /dir2/f3 … ]]
```

If you have exactly one file in each directory,
this *should* work precariously. 
Otherwise, the command is nonsense, and will fail.

You need to use `-nt` on just two files at a time. 
You might want to do something like

```
for b in /home/filepath/*.mp3
do
    b_base="${b##*/}"
    if [[ /media/pi/"b_base" -nt "$b" ]] ; then (do something) …
            ︙
```

Also, you’re using `&` where you should be using `&&`.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I'm still pretty new to coding like this, if you have the time could you breakdown what's happening in the second solution "for b in ...."